# Not able to install VLC 1.1

Tags: software-installation, 10.04, vlc

I am trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

They give these commands to install VLC 1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lucid-bleed/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

But the last command returns:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
mozilla-plugin-vlc: 
Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.5-1ubuntu2~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed 
vlc:
Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.5-1ubuntu2~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1.1.5-1ubuntu2~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed  
vlc-plugin-pulse: 
Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.5-1ubuntu2~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Can any one help me to install VLC on Ubuntu 10.04.

**NOTE:** Same error displayed while installing from synaptic package manager

Screen shots from synaptic package manager:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Screen shots from terminal:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Screen shot of error while installing from http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc :

[image]

Comment: People out there..Please help me..

Comment: First remove vlc completely and then reinstall it again **"sudo apt-get remove vlc --purge"**           
                                                         **"rm -fr ~/.vlc"**
                                                          **"sudo apt-get install vlc"**

Answer (score 5):

**Installing VLC Player in Ubuntu 10.04**
By Using Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager:

1. Open SPM (Synaptic Package Manager) (Administration → Synaptic Package Manager) or Ubuntu Software Center (Applications) and Search for vlc player.
2. Check the the box to install and apply (Required in SPM).
3. Downloading and installation will complete within few minutes.
4. That’s all.

**By Using Ubuntu Terminal**

1. Open Terminal - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or open it from Applications → Accessories → Terminal.
2. Type the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vlc
   ```
3. It may ask you to enter the user password. if so, then enter your password. Then downloading will begin and installation will also finish within moments.
4. Now, I assume you have successfully installed vlc player on Ubuntu 10.04.

**Note:** You should add the repository before installing **VLC**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-media-player-development/development
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Alternatively, you can click on the links below to install:

- [vlc](http://apt.ubuntu.com/vlc) [image: Install vlc]
- [vlc-nox](http://apt.ubuntu.com/vlc-nox) [image: Install vlc-nox]

Also see this [**post**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1477045) if you wanna install VLC offline.

If any thing goes wrong during this steps, let me know through comments.

Comment: Karthick thanks for ur time...Could you please let me know if the above method will install VLC 1.1 or 1.0?

Comment: It will install the latest

Comment: I tried the same method u mentioned using synaptic package manager and i got the below error:   `vlc:
 Depends: vlc-nox but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: First of all have you added the repository?

Comment: which repository? Could you tell me which one to add? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Type this in terminal `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-media-player-development/development` After entering this you should update your repository so enter this in terminal to update `sudo apt-get update` And to install vlc type `sudo apt-get install vlc` in terminal.

Comment: I am getting the below output for the first command :    `Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1937F4A14D997BCF2C80235C64A9CDD77362E5D0
gpg: requesting key 7362E5D0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7362E5D0: "Launchpad GNOME Media Player Development PPA" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1` Is it correct Still same error

Comment: Are you installing vlc from the local server?Goto System-->Administration-->Software Sources And be sure that you have set Download from to **Main Server**.

Comment: I think you are getting gpg warning read this post http://blog.mansonthomas.com/2009/01/how-to-solve-gpg-warning-about.html

Comment: Karthick..I have uploaded the screen shots..Can you look at them?

Comment: I am not getting any gpg warnings as mentioned in this link http://blog.mansonthomas.com/2009/01/how-to-solve-gpg-warning-about.html..        However i followed the steps mentioned there..and still it is not working

Comment: Go to System-->Administration-->Synaptic Package Manager-->Edit-->Fix Broken Packages. This should repair the problem and allow you to install vlc.

Comment: Ok..Did that. I got the message as `Successfully fixed dependency problems` Still getting the same error.. Thanks for your help yaar

Comment: Type **vlc** in terminal and see what happens.Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after fixing the dependency problem?

Comment: Screen shot of typing vlc in terminal

![Screen shot][1]


  [1]: http://i51.tinypic.com/23j083t.png

Comment: Yes..I ran `sudo apt-get update` after fix broken packages option

Comment: See my post install vlc-nox from there.

Comment: Can u give me link for that?

Comment: Try installing this and tell me what happens            `sudo apt-get install libvlc2`

Comment: This is the link for **vlc-nox** package http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vlc-nox&searchon=names&suite=lucid&section=all

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libvlc2` is giving `libvlc2: Depends: libvlccore2` error

Comment: and http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc-nox is giving you have held broken packages erorr

Comment: And this(http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc-nox_1.0.6-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb) is giving cannot install libvlc2 error

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Tried this `sudo apt-get install -f` still it is not working.. I am going mad because of this

Comment: guys, please do your troubleshooting in your questions and answers, at this point I can't even follow what's going on.