# vlc installs, but not on system?

Tags: package-management, vlc

Dear Ubuntu community,

This is very strange to me.  I added the nightly build ppa for vlc, installed vlc, removed vlc, then removed ppa.  Now I am stuck:

```
$ sudo apt-get  install vlc

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree  

Reading state information... Done

vlc is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ which vlc

$ /usr/bin/vlc

bash: /usr/bin/vlc: No such file or directory

$ vlc

The program 'vlc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:

sudo apt-get install vlc-nox
```

Same issues:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  vlc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 4,898 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 210454 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing vlc (2.2.0-1) ...
Purging configuration files for vlc (2.2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.2.0-1) ...
$ sudo apt-get update
[[cut]]
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  videolan-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vlc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,495 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,898 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package vlc.
(Reading database ... 210397 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/vlc_2.2.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc (2.2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up vlc (2.2.0-1) ...
$ vlc
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install vlc-nox
```

So strange to me...

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc-nox 
Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree        Reading state information... Done vlc-nox is
already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
and 0 not upgraded.
```

More info:

```
$ apt-cache policy vlc vlc-nox
vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.0-1
  Candidate: 2.2.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
vlc-nox:
  Installed: 2.2.0-1
  Candidate: 2.2.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How is this possible:

```
# apt-get remove --purge vlc Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The following packages will be REMOVED:   vlc* 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded. After this operation, 4,898 kB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n Abort.
# vlc The program 'vlc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install vlc-nox
```

Comment: $ uname -a
Linux HOST 3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.04
Release: 15.04
Codename: vivid

Comment: run `sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc` then update package list and install it again.

Comment: Setting up vlc (2.2.0-1) ...
$ vlc
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: install that package `sudo apt-get install vlc-nox`

Comment: `vlc-nox is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Check this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/14261/not-able-to-install-vlc-1-1 whether this helps.

Comment: See also `dpkg -L vlc` and `dpkg -L vlc-nox` to see what files the packages are actually installing.

Comment: what is the output for `apt-cache policy vlc vlc-nox` if the output's big paste it to pastebin.com and link here

Comment: Output of `dpkg -L vlc` and `dpkg -L vlc-nox`  looks reasonable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was `sudo apt-get purge vlc-data`

Thanks for all the help!